# Parse a python file to a XML template in Apache Velocity

Tags: python, xml, velocity

I have a Python source file which I would like to convert, according to a certain template written in Apache Velocity, to an XML file.
Is it possible to read the contents of a python code file and extract the necessary information in native Velocity language? Or do I need to write  a python script (or some other language)to parse the python file to the xml template?

Answer (score 0):

As you have identified, you need to have two distinct phases:

1. Extract information from the Python source file (aka parsing)
2. Publish this information back to an XML file

Apache Velocity can help you accomplish step 1, but knows nothing about parsing.

There are several ways to achieve the parsing step:

- you could parse it with whatever tool you like, and publish it in a format easily understandable for Velocity, like a Properties file that you would put in the context. If you need to use hierarchical properties, have a look at the ValueParser tool, which can return submaps from sets of properties like `foo.bar=woogie` and `foo.schmoo=wiggie`.
- you could give a try to [Stillness](https://github.com/arkanovicz/stillness), a parsing tool that uses a Velocity-like syntax (disclaimer: I wrote it).